# How to get unique values from 2 columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, exclusion-constraint

i have a column **"id_a"** and a column **"id_b"**.

**"id_a"** is an integer[] type.

**"id_b"** is an int type.

I have to find a way to verify that there are no more values ​​of id_a with the same id_b

```
For Example:
id_a {3,4,5}    id_b 18
```

**Other Examples:**

```
ERROR:
id_a{3,4,5}  id_b 18 --> because i have already the value of b with the same values of a 

NO ERROR:
id_a{3,4,5}  id_b 19

ANOTHER ERROR:
id_a{3}      id_b 19

NO ERROR:
id_a{6}      id_b 18
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would like to create a constrains, I had thought about using UNIQUE but i can't figure out how to use it on different types.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
so i should change the type of my column  "Id_a" to from Integer [] to int? 
and for example have values ​​like these?
ROW 1: name: abc     id_a   3        id_b   18
ROW 2: name: cba     id_a   4        id_b   18

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am currently using version 12.4, sorry for the wrong tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) if you install the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) extension:

```
create table data (id_a int[], id_b int);

alter table data
  add constraint check_ids 
  exclude using gist (id_a with &&, id_b with =);
```

Initial row - no problem

```
insert into data (id_a, id_b) values ('{3,4,5}', 18);
```

Running the above again yields an error as expected.

The following works:

```
insert into data (id_a, id_b) values ('{3,4,5}', 19);
```

And then:

```
insert into data (id_a, id_b) values ('{3}', 19);
```

will result in an error

> ERROR: conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "check_ids"

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=08f0199075dc9433b5f8ac518d89d7ea)

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know you could have a GiST index on arrays.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: only if you install the btree_gist extension

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exclusion constraint, like so:

```
create table mytable (
    id_a int[],
    id_b int,
    exclude using gist(id_a with &&, id_b with =)
);
```

This prevents array overlaps on `id_a` for a given `id_b`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c512749b60902ad508ef864bab6550fa)**:

```
insert into mytable values ('{3,4,5}', 18);
-- 1 rows affected

insert into mytable values ('{3,4,5}', 18);
-- ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "mytable_id_a_id_b_excl"
-- DETAIL:  Key (id_a, id_b)=({3,4,5}, 18) conflicts with existing key (id_a, id_b)=({3,4,5}, 18).

insert into mytable values ('{3,4,5}', 19);
-- 1 rows affected

insert into mytable values ('{3}', 19);
-- ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "mytable_id_a_id_b_excl"
-- DETAIL:  Key (id_a, id_b)=({3}, 19) conflicts with existing key (id_a, id_b)=({3,4,5}, 19).

insert into mytable values ('{6}', 18);
-- 1 rows affected
```